# GSheet Excel Export - Folder Path Method for Shared Drive

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Alright, team,

Here's a little Google Script I wrote, it accomplishes what it's supposed to do but it's not very....elegant...maybe there's another way to go about it that I don't know.

The objective is to export GSheet tabs into Excel files, and save them in a specific folder on a company Shared Drive called "Weekly Appendices". The GSheet is also on the Shared Drive and the folder structure breakdown is project-specific.

They are 3 Sheets that need to be exported, and I use the URL to extract the ID and save it as an excel.

The issue I have is with finding the folder path to save the exports. I used the following method to find to proper folder Weekly Appendices in the Shared Drive:

```
 var ssparents = DriveApp.getFileById(SSid).getParents().next().getId();
 var saveFolderID = DriveApp.getFolderById(ssparents).getParents().next().getFoldersByName("08-Reports").next().getFoldersByName("03-Weekly").next().getFoldersByName("Weekly Appendices").next().getId();
```

I'll admit I don't fully understand how to use the FolderIterator, but the above code somewhat works.
I'll share the rest of the code below, but the above illustrates the path problem.
There's is a constraint that prevents me from using the FolderID number to make a direct reference.
The constraint is: The GSheet is used on several projects on the same Shared Drive that has an identical folder structure. Therefore, the management wants to able to copy/paste the GSheet and have it ready to use elsewhere in the drive. So if you are following me, the folder path to Weekly Appendices is always the same, but the folderID changes when the GSheet is copied into a new project. Hence, why I tried this method instead of using FolderID for Weekly Appendices.

This method is finicky, sometimes it doesn't work for a reason I can't figure, but a simple reset or changing folder name fixes the problem. So if any of you have some feedback I'd love to hear it.

Here's the rest of the code:

```
 function exportSpreadsheet(){

          //Copy sheets to export tab
    CopyCP(); 
    SpreadsheetApp.flush();
    CopyRFI();
    SpreadsheetApp.flush();
    CopyTrend();
    SpreadsheetApp.flush();

            //export date for document title

    const date = new Date();
    const nextDate = new Date();
    nextDate.setDate(date.getDate() -1);
    var weekEndDate = Utilities.formatDate(nextDate,"GMT-6", "yyyy-MM-dd");
    console.log(weekEndDate)

            //URL extraction for Excel export

    var SS = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();

      var SSid = SS.getId();

      var RFIWeekly = SS.getSheetByName("Export RFI Weekly Report");
      var RFIid = RFIWeekly.getSheetId();

      var CPWeekly = SS.getSheetByName("Export CP Weekly Report");
      var CPid = CPWeekly.getSheetId();

      var TrendWeekly = SS.getSheetByName("Export Trend Weekly Report");
      var Trendid = TrendWeekly.getSheetId();


      var urlCP = "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/"+SSid+"/export?format=xlsx&gid="+CPid;
      var urlRFI = "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/"+SSid+"/export?format=xlsx&gid="+RFIid;
      var urlTrend = "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/"+SSid+"/export?format=xlsx&gid="+Trendid;

          

    var ssparents = DriveApp.getFileById(SSid).getParents().next().getId();
    var saveFolderID = DriveApp.getFolderById(ssparents).getParents().next().getFoldersByName("08-Reports").next().getFoldersByName("03-Weekly").next().getFoldersByName("Weekly Appendices").next().getId();


        var params = {method:"GET",headers:{"authorization":"Bearer "+ ScriptApp.getOAuthToken()}};

              //Save CP

      var responseCP = UrlFetchApp.fetch(urlCP, params).getBlob();

      DriveApp.getFolderById(saveFolderID).createFile(responseCP).setName("Appendix D CP Log -" + weekEndDate);

              //Save RFI

       var responseRFI = UrlFetchApp.fetch(urlRFI, params).getBlob();

      DriveApp.getFolderById(saveFolderID).createFile(responseRFI).setName("Appendix C RFI Log -" + weekEndDate);


              //Save Trend

       var responseTrend = UrlFetchApp.fetch(urlTrend, params).getBlob();

      DriveApp.getFolderById(saveFolderID).createFile(responseTrend).setName("Appendix E Trend Log - " + weekEndDate);

     }
```

Comment: At first, I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand about your current issue of your script. Can I ask you about the detail of your current issue and your goal?

Comment: The issue here is to find the folder ID you want to save the file to?

Comment: Sorry I'm re-reading my post and I can see how it's not clear. 

Yes, the issue is that the script doesn't always find the folderID for "Weekly Appendices". Sometimes it does and sometimes it doesn't. Even if the folder path, as described in the code, never changes. I already made sure all the strings match.

The goal is:
I want to save the Excel export in the "Weekly Appendices" folder, which is located elsewhere in the Shared Drive. As I've mentioned, they are several folders with the exact same name. Hence why I tried to "hard code" the folder path to the proper "Weekly Appendices".

Comment: Have you checked using [Properties Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/properties) to save there the Id of the folder, that way you would not "hard code" the ID on the script, but you won't have to search for it each time

Comment: I wasn't familiar with property service until I saw your reply. I think this could work, I'll give it a shot. Thank you for the suggestion.